# Postgres period query

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have a table which looks like the following:

```
 index  | timestamp         | type | value 
------- | ----------------- | ---- | ----- 
  1     | 2014-07-10 10:00  | A    | 56
  2     | 2014-07-10 11:04  | B    | 69
  3     | 2014-07-10 11:06  | C    | 68
  4     | 2014-07-10 10:03  | B    | 60
  5     | 2014-07-11 10:03  | B    | 18
  6     | 2014-07-11 11:03  | C    | 48
```

I am willing to select a period of values for certain 'types'.

The problem is that I also need the result to include the last value of each type before the selected period starts.

Any idea if it is possible to achieve with a single query (or at list limited number of queries)?

Thanks
Meir

Comment: please add expected result for the data set above.

Comment: Selecting all types for perid `timestamp >= '2014-07-11'`, I want to have all lines except 4 (because last value of type B before 2014-07-11 is in line 2)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found my own answer

```
SELECT timestamp, type, value
FROM   table
where timestamp >= '2014-07-11'
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct on (type) timestamp, type, value
FROM   table
where timestamp < '2014-07-11'
ORDER BY type, timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function especially rank() :

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

you will have somethink like :

```
select * from (
    select ...., rank() over (partition by type order by timestamp desc) as rk 
    where ... 
) where rk=1;
```

I don't remember if you can put 'rk' in a 'having' clause of the inner query, but I'm pretty sure I already try that once, and postgres did not accept that